# Select entre varias tablas MYSQL WORKBENCH

Tags: select, mysql-workbench

Qué tal,

Mi cuestión es, tengo varias tablas, las cuáles muestro a continuación en dónde resalto los datos relevantes para la consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero realizar una consulta, en dónde me de la cantidad de alumnos por semestre de cada Programa. 
Algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una consula que me da en qué semestre va cada alumno:

```
SELECT idProgram, MAX(Semestre) FROM Alumno, 
Materia a INNER JOIN Historial n ON a.idMateria = n.claveMateria 
GROUP BY idAlum;
```

La cuál está mal, debido a que me pone solo un Programa en lugar del respectivo de cada alumno.

Tengo otras consultas que me dan indicadores por carrera, sin embargo la ventaja de ellas es que los datos están en una sola tabla (Alumno):

```
SELECT c.idPrograma as Licenciatura, sum(field(a.Estado_Alu,'CURSANDO')) as 
CURSANDO, sum(field(a.Estado_Alu,'BAJA TEMPORAL')) as BAJA_TEMPORAL,
sum(field(a.Estado_Alu,'BAJA ABSOLUTA')) as BAJA_ABSOLUTA,
sum(field(a.Estado_Alu,'EGRESADO')) as EGRESADO,
sum(field(a.Estado_Alu,'INTERCAMBIO')) as INTERCAMBIO,
count(a.idAlumno) as Total
FROM alumno a
join Programa c on a.idProgram=c.idPrograma
group by a.idProgram;
```

La cuál me retorna esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Me retorna muchos renglones con un solo programa, y un solo semestre cada renglón.

Answer (score 1):

No tengo forma de probarlo de momento, pero se me hace que esto generaría lo que buscas:

```
SELECT Materia.idProgra, Historial.semes, count(Historial.idAlum) 
FROM Materia JOIN Historial ON Materia.IdMateria = Historial.claveMateria 
GROUP BY Materia.idProgra, Histrial.semes;
```

Comment: Me retorno, en el campo de idProgra solo un programa no los respectivos a los que está inscrito el alumno, sin embargo, si me dio pie para otra consulta, gracias.

Comment: bueno, si requieres algo, solo avisa.  Saludos